# YOLO V8 - TIEMPO DE ESPERA PARA DETECCION

Tags: python, yolo

He desarrollado un entrenamiento con YOLO V8 para su posterior implementación en un aplicativo mediante Python. Mi consulta es, si hay la manera de que una vez detecte un objeto, se pueda establecer un tiempo de espera para que detecte nuevamente.
He usado time.sleep(), pero la ventana de detección se congela una vez detecta y pasa el tiempo para la próxima detección, pero no quiero se paralice la ventana.
Alguna sugerencia o forma en que se pueda realizar esto.

Adjunto fragmento de codigo donde detecta:

```
                    if cls == 0:
                        # DIBUJAR RECTANGULO
                        cv2.rectangle(frame_show, (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(81,209,246),2)

                        # TEXTO
                        text = f'{clsName[cls]}'
                        print(text)
                        if text == 'CARTON':
                            ser.write(b'3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Si como parece estas usando OpenCV para mostrar y/o obtener las imágenes, seguramente tendrás un main loop, un ciclo `while` para procesar las imágenes y responder a eventos.

En tal caso, en vez de usar `time.sleep()` que es bloqueante, puedes usar un *timer* a través de un simple condicional en el ciclo:

```
import time


TIEMPO_DE_ESPERA = 5  # Tiempo de espera en segundos


t0 = time.perf_counter()
while True:
    # Código a ejecutar sin bloquear
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    if t1 - t0 > TIEMPO_DE_ESPERA:
        # Código a ejecutar cada vez que se cumpla el tiempo
        t0 = t1
```